# Twilio: SMS not sent

Tags: sms, twilio

At the end of a call, I want to send an SMS with a link to the recording of the conversation to the caller and to a control number.

I have two TwiML bins. The first one handles dialing and recording, then directs the call to the second bin. This works well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual" timeLimit="600" action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <Number>{{Digits}}</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Here's the second bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Sms from="+XXXXXXXXX" to="{{From}}">Here's the recording of your call: {{RecordingUrl}}</Sms>
    <Sms from="+XXXXXXXXX" to="+YYYYYYYYYY">Call recorded from {{From}} to {{To}}.</Sms>
</Response>
```

From the log, I see the TwiML bin was successfully called. Status code is 200. The {{From}} number was correctly replaced.

**However, no SMS is sent. No SMS appears in the SMS log. No SMS is received if I do a call myself. Despite that, no error message appear in the call log or in the debugger.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As we've discussed in your other question, `<Sms>` uses the deprecated SMS/Messages resource under the hood. Therefore it doesn't come with good logging.

I recommend using the [Messages resource of the REST API to send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) instead. You can't do that with a TwiML Bin, but you can with [Twilio Functions](http://twilio.com/functions).

In the [config section for Functions](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/configure) make sure the "Enable ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN" check box is ticked. [Create a new Function in your Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/manage) and enter the following code (replace the placeholders for real numbers):

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  const message1 = client.messages.create({
    from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
    to: event.From,
    body: `Here's the recording of your call: ${event.RecordingUrl}`
  });

  const message2 = client.messages.create({
    from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
    to: THAT_OTHER_NUMBER,
    body: `Call recorded from ${event.From} to ${event.To}.`
  })

  Promise.all([message1, message2]).then(() => { 
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    callback(null, twiml);  
  }, err => {
    callback(err);
  })
};
```

Give the function a path and then copy the whole URL and use it as the action attribute in the `<Dial>` in your first TwiML Bin.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hey again! Ok that works better, the underlying problem was that the 1st number didn't have correct Geo Permissions. Now at least the other message is sent correctly. However the fact that the 1st message failed because of geo permissions doesn't appear in the debugger, in the call logs, or in the SMS logs. It only appears in the Function logs, which are flushed when I refresh the page from what I see. Is that normal?

Comment: Well, making HTTP calls from the function is like making HTTP calls from your own server, so the errors won't appear in the debugger, call logs or SMS logs. I'm just finding out whether the function logs are stored anywhere for review.

Comment: I hear that historical logs are in the roadmap as Functions progresses through its public beta stage. So you will be able to see errors in these logs.

Comment: Ok thanks for your research. Well actually in the call log you can see the request returned with status code 500. I think it should be made clearer at the top of the call log that something went wrong down the road.

Comment: Did that 500 not show up as an alert in the [debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger)?

Comment: No, and the line for this call in the call log list doesn't appear orange or red either.

Comment: I shall investigate this too :)